# Combine 5 queries into 1 so that I only return 9 rows and not 23

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have 5 separate queries that I need to combine into 1. This is all in a SQL Server db. The queries are pulling back paycheck information. I've tried using `join` but that multiplies the number of rows, I've tried using `union` but that gives me 23 rows. I only want 9 rows.

Here is an example: *(I am shortening the number of tables actually involved in gathering this data to make it easier to show the example, assume that each query involves 4-7 tables already joined in the below example)*

#### Employee

| Company | Process Level | Department | Employee ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 950 | 100 | 654321 | 543 |
| 950 | 100 | 654321 | 321 |

#### PSG

| PSG Check Description | Hours | Wage Amt | Check ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PTO | 24 | 1249.92 | 987654 |
| PTO | 24 | 1249.92 | 987654 |
| SAL | 16 | 833.28 | 987654 |
| SAL | 16 | 833.28 | 987654 |
| CELLALL | 0 | 23.08 | 987654 |
| SAL | 40 | 2083.20 | 123456 |
| SAL | 40 | 2083.20 | 123456 |
| CELLALL | 0 | 23.08 | 123456 |

#### Deductions

| Ded Description | Ded Amt | Tax Wage | Ded Code | Check ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| FITREG | 534.49 | 3519.09 | 1 | 987654 |
| FMEDEE | 58.31 | 4021.83 | 1 | 987654 |
| FSOCEE | 249.35 | 4021.83 | 1 | 987654 |
| LAITREG | 154.92 | 3519.09 | 1 | 987654 |
| FITREG | 534.49 | 3519.09 | 1 | 123456 |
| FMEDEE | 58.31 | 4021.83 | 1 | 123456 |
| FSOCEE | 249.35 | 4021.83 | 1 | 123456 |
| 401K | 502.74 |  | 2 | 987654 |
| Dental | 12.62 |  | 2 | 987654 |
| FlexMed | 60.00 |  | 2 | 987654 |
| IdentShd | 3.46 |  | 2 | 987654 |
| Medical | 84.41 |  | 2 | 987654 |
| Vision | 2.34 |  | 2 | 987654 |
| VolCan | 8.28 |  | 2 | 987654 |
| VolLifCh | 0.66 |  | 2 | 987654 |
| VolLifEE | 27.00 |  | 2 | 987654 |
| 401K | 502.74 |  | 2 | 123456 |
| Dental | 12.62 |  | 2 | 123456 |
| FlexMed | 60.00 |  | 2 | 123456 |
| IdentShd | 3.46 |  | 2 | 123456 |
| Medical | 84.41 |  | 2 | 123456 |
| Vision | 2.34 |  | 2 | 123456 |
| VolCan | 8.28 |  | 2 | 123456 |
| VolLifCh | 0.66 |  | 2 | 123456 |
| VolLifEE | 27.00 |  | 2 | 123456 |
| 401kER | 83.79 | 0.00 | 3 | 987654 |
| AD&D | 0.75 | 0.00 | 3 | 987654 |
| FMEDER | 58.32 | 4021.83 | 3 | 987654 |
| FSOCER | 249.35 | 4021.83 | 3 | 987654 |
| LTD | 8.41 | 0.00 | 3 | 987654 |
| Life | 1.75 | 0.00 | 3 | 987654 |
| MedicaER | 206.66 | 0.00 | 3 | 987654 |
| 401kER | 83.79 | 0.00 | 3 | 123456 |
| AD&D | 0.75 | 0.00 | 3 | 123456 |
| FMEDER | 58.32 | 4021.83 | 3 | 123456 |
| FSOCER | 249.35 | 4021.83 | 3 | 123456 |
| LTD | 8.41 | 0.00 | 3 | 123456 |
| Life | 1.75 | 0.00 | 3 | 123456 |
| MedicaER | 206.66 | 0.00 | 3 | 123456 |

#### Check

| Check Nbr | Check ID | Employee ID | Net | Gross | Tax | Company Ded | Other |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 123456 | 543 | 2490.90 | 4189.48 | 997.07 | 609.02 | 701.51 |
| 98 | 987654 | 321 | 2490.90 | 4189.48 | 997.07 | 609.02 | 701.51 |

**Sample Queries**

```
Query 1: returns 1 row
select e.Company, e.'Process Level', e.Department, c.Gross, c.Tax, c.'Company Ded', c.Other, c.Net
from Employee e
Join Check c on c.'Employee ID' = e.'Employee ID'

Query 2: returns 3 rows
Select p.'PSG Check Description', SUM(p.Hours) as 'Hours', SUM(p.'Wage Amt') as 'Wage Amt'
from PSG p
Join Check c on c.'Check ID' = p.'Check ID'
Group By p.'PSG Check Description'

Query 3: returns 4 rows
Select d.'Ded Description', d.'Ded Amt' as 'Tax Ded', d.'Tax Wage'
from Deductions d
Join Check c on c.'Check ID' = d.'Check ID' and d.'Ded Code' = 1

Query 4: returns 9 rows
Select d.'Ded Description', d.'Ded Amt' as 'Tax Ded', d.'Tax Wage'
from Deductions d
Join Check c on c.'Check ID' = d.'Check ID' and d.'Ded Code' = 2

Query 5: returns 7 rows
Select d.'Ded Description', d.'Ded Amt' as 'Tax Ded', d.'Tax Wage'
from Deductions d
Join Check c on c.'Check ID' = d.'Check ID' and d.'Ded Code' = 3
```

**Results:**

**Query 1:**

| Company | Process Level | Department | Employee | Gross | Tax | Company Ded | Other | Net |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 950 | 100 | 654321 | 543 | 4189.48 | 997.07 | 609.02 | 701.51 | 2490.90 |
| 950 | 100 | 654321 | 321 | 4189.48 | 997.07 | 609.02 | 701.51 | 2490.90 |

**Query 2:**

| PSG Check Description | Hours | Wage Amt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| PTO | 48 | 2499.84 |
| SAL | 32 | 1666.56 |
| CELLALL | 0 | 23.08 |

**Query 3:**

| Ded Description | Tax Ded | Tax Wage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| FITREG | 534.49 | 3519.09 |
| FMEDEE | 58.31 | 4021.83 |
| FSOCEE | 249.35 | 4021.83 |
| LAITREG | 154.92 | 3519.09 |

**Query 4:**

| Ded Description | Tax Ded | Tax Wage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 401K | 502.74 |  |
| Dental | 12.62 |  |
| FlexMed | 60.00 |  |
| IdentShd | 3.46 |  |
| Medical | 84.41 |  |
| Vision | 2.34 |  |
| VolCan | 8.28 |  |
| VolLifCh | 0.66 |  |
| VolLifEE | 27.00 |  |

**Query 5:**

| Ded Description | Tax Ded | Tax Wage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 401kER | 83.79 | 0.00 |
| AD&D | 0.75 | 0.00 |
| FMEDER | 58.31 | 4021.83 |
| FSOCER | 249.35 | 4021.83 |
| LTD | 8.41 | 0.00 |
| Life | 1.75 | 0.00 |
| MedicaER | 206.66 | 0.00 |

I can `join` each of queries 2,3,4,5 to query 1 and get the 3,4,9, or 7 rows that I need, but if I `join` a 3rd query then it multiplies the number of results. For example if I `join` queries 1,2, and 3 I get 12 rows returned.

If I use several `unions` and have `null as 'Company'` for all the missing data in each of the queries then I get 23 rows returned.

I am probably over thinking this, but I cannot come up with something that will return just 9 rows so that it looks like this:

| Company | Process Level | Department | Employee | Gross | Tax | Company Ded | Other | Net | PSG Check Description | Hours | Wage Amt | Ded Description | Tax Ded | Tax Wage | Ded Description 2 | Tax Ded 2 | Tax Wage 2 | Ded Description 3 | Tax Ded 3 | Tax Wage 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 950 | 100 | 654321 | 543 | 4189.48 | 997.07 | 609.02 | 701.51 | 2490.90 | PTO | 48 | 2499.84 | FITREG | 534.49 | 3519.09 | 401K | 502.74 |  | 401kER | 83.79 | 0.00 |
| 950 | 100 | 654321 | 543 | 4189.48 | 997.07 | 609.02 | 701.51 | 2490.90 | SAL | 32 | 1666.56 | FMEDEE | 58.31 | 4021.83 | Dental | 12.62 |  | AD&D | 0.75 | 0.00 |
| 950 | 100 | 654321 | 543 | 4189.48 | 997.07 | 609.02 | 701.51 | 2490.90 | CELLALL | 0 | 23.08 | FSOCEE | 249.35 | 4021.83 | FlexMed | 60.00 |  | FMEDER | 58.31 | 4021.83 |
| 950 | 100 | 654321 | 543 | 4189.48 | 997.07 | 609.02 | 701.51 | 2490.90 |  |  |  | LAITREG | 154.92 | 3519.09 | IdentShd | 3.46 |  | FSOCER | 249.35 | 4021.83 |
| 950 | 100 | 654321 | 543 | 4189.48 | 997.07 | 609.02 | 701.51 | 2490.90 |  |  |  |  |  |  | Medical | 84.41 |  | LTD | 8.41 | 0.00 |
| 950 | 100 | 654321 | 543 | 4189.48 | 997.07 | 609.02 | 701.51 | 2490.90 |  |  |  |  |  |  | Vision | 2.34 |  | Life | 1.75 | 0.00 |
| 950 | 100 | 654321 | 543 | 4189.48 | 997.07 | 609.02 | 701.51 | 2490.90 |  |  |  |  |  |  | VolCan | 8.28 |  | MedicaER | 206.66 | 0.00 |
| 950 | 100 | 654321 | 543 | 4189.48 | 997.07 | 609.02 | 701.51 | 2490.90 |  |  |  |  |  |  | VolLifCh | 0.66 |  |  |  |  |
| 950 | 100 | 654321 | 543 | 4189.48 | 997.07 | 609.02 | 701.51 | 2490.90 |  |  |  |  |  |  | VolLifEE | 27.00 |  |  |  |  |
| 950 | 100 | 654321 | 321 | 4189.48 | 997.07 | 609.02 | 701.51 | 2490.90 | PTO | 48 | 2499.84 | FITREG | 534.49 | 3519.09 | 401K | 502.74 |  | 401kER | 83.79 | 0.00 |
| 950 | 100 | 654321 | 321 | 4189.48 | 997.07 | 609.02 | 701.51 | 2490.90 | SAL | 32 | 1666.56 | FMEDEE | 58.31 | 4021.83 | Dental | 12.62 |  | AD&D | 0.75 | 0.00 |
| 950 | 100 | 654321 | 321 | 4189.48 | 997.07 | 609.02 | 701.51 | 2490.90 | CELLALL | 0 | 23.08 | FSOCEE | 249.35 | 4021.83 | FlexMed | 60.00 |  | FMEDER | 58.31 | 4021.83 |
| 950 | 100 | 654321 | 321 | 4189.48 | 997.07 | 609.02 | 701.51 | 2490.90 |  |  |  | LAITREG | 154.92 | 3519.09 | IdentShd | 3.46 |  | FSOCER | 249.35 | 4021.83 |
| 950 | 100 | 654321 | 321 | 4189.48 | 997.07 | 609.02 | 701.51 | 2490.90 |  |  |  |  |  |  | Medical | 84.41 |  | LTD | 8.41 | 0.00 |
| 950 | 100 | 654321 | 321 | 4189.48 | 997.07 | 609.02 | 701.51 | 2490.90 |  |  |  |  |  |  | Vision | 2.34 |  | Life | 1.75 | 0.00 |
| 950 | 100 | 654321 | 321 | 4189.48 | 997.07 | 609.02 | 701.51 | 2490.90 |  |  |  |  |  |  | VolCan | 8.28 |  | MedicaER | 206.66 | 0.00 |
| 950 | 100 | 654321 | 321 | 4189.48 | 997.07 | 609.02 | 701.51 | 2490.90 |  |  |  |  |  |  | VolLifCh | 0.66 |  |  |  |  |
| 950 | 100 | 654321 | 321 | 4189.48 | 997.07 | 609.02 | 701.51 | 2490.90 |  |  |  |  |  |  | VolLifEE | 27.00 |  |  |  |  |

Even if it has `null` in all the empty fields that is fine, I just need it to only return the 9 rows (per Employee ID).

Comment: What I believe you will need to do is assign row numbers to the result of each subquery, partitioned by check number, that can then be used to match up and join  the rows horizontally.  Those combined results can then be joined back with the check and employee tables. I don't have a existing example handy, but if you give me a few minutes, I can put something together.

Comment: Can you confirm that you are using Microsoft SQL Server? Your sample queries are using a quoted identifier syntax not supported by SQL Server. In SQL server, you can reference `e.[Process Level]` (square brackets) or `e."Process Level"` (double quotes), but not `e.'Process Level'` (single quotes).

Comment: @TN Yes, I am using SQL Server, I didn't copy/paste the queries, just typed it out using the sample tables that I created. The sample tables are actually part of what is returned from a couple of other queries. In all there were some 9 separate queries that I was trying to tie together. The syntax in my sample queries above is more laziness than anything else, just not wanting to hit one extra button or stretch my pinky up any further than I could quickly. And since the single quote is right there, that is what I used even though it's not correct syntax for SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following uses CTEs (Common table Expressions) to assign row numbers for each PSG and deduction entry per Check ID. It then figures out the max rows required per Check ID. Finally, it joins all of the data together, matching the Check ID and assigned row numbers for each row of the result.

```
;WITH CTE_PSG AS (
    SELECT
        p.CheckID,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY p.CheckID ORDER BY p.PSGCheckDescription) AS RowNum,
        p.PSGCheckDescription, SUM(p.Hours) as Hours, SUM(p.WageAmt) as WageAmt
    FROM PSG p
    GROUP BY p.CheckID, p.PSGCheckDescription
),
CTE_Deductions1 AS (
    SELECT
        d.CheckID,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY d.CheckID ORDER BY d.DedDescription) AS RowNum,
        d.DedDescription, d.DedAmt as TaxDed, d.TaxWage
    FROM Deductions d
    WHERE d.DedCode = 1
),
CTE_Deductions2 AS (
    SELECT
        d.CheckID,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY d.CheckID ORDER BY d.DedDescription) AS RowNum,
        d.DedDescription, d.DedAmt as TaxDed, d.TaxWage
    FROM Deductions d
    WHERE d.DedCode = 2
),
CTE_Deductions3 AS (
    SELECT
        d.CheckID,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY d.CheckID ORDER BY d.DedDescription) AS RowNum,
        d.DedDescription, d.DedAmt as TaxDed, d.TaxWage
    FROM Deductions d
    WHERE d.DedCode = 3
),
CTE_RowNumbers AS (
    -- We need to combined row numbers to make the final select easier
    SELECT p.CheckID, p.RowNum FROM CTE_PSG p
    UNION
    SELECT d.CheckID, d.RowNum FROM CTE_Deductions1 d
    UNION
    SELECT d.CheckID, d.RowNum FROM CTE_Deductions2 d
    UNION
    SELECT d.CheckID, d.RowNum FROM CTE_Deductions3 d
)
SELECT *
FROM Employee e
JOIN [Check] c ON c.EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID
LEFT JOIN CTE_RowNumbers rn ON rn.CheckID = c.CheckID
LEFT JOIN CTE_PSG p ON p.CheckID = rn.CheckID AND p.RowNum = rn.RowNum
LEFT JOIN CTE_Deductions1 d1 ON d1.CheckID = rn.CheckID AND d1.RowNum = rn.RowNum
LEFT JOIN CTE_Deductions2 d2 ON d2.CheckID = rn.CheckID AND d2.RowNum = rn.RowNum
LEFT JOIN CTE_Deductions3 d3 ON d3.CheckID = rn.CheckID AND d3.RowNum = rn.RowNum
ORDER BY e.EmployeeID, c.CheckID, rn.RowNum
```

Results:

| Company | ProcessLevel | Department | EmployeeID | CheckNbr | CheckID | EmployeeID | Net | Gross | Tax | CompanyDed | Other | CheckID | RN | CheckID | RN | PSGCheckDescription | Hours | WageAmt | CheckID | RN | DedDescription | TaxDed | TaxWage | CheckID | RN | DedDescription | TaxDed | TaxWage | CheckID | RN | DedDescription | TaxDed | TaxWage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 950 | 100 | 654321 | 543 | 12 | 123456 | 543 | 2490.9000 | 4189.4800 | 997.0700 | 609.0200 | 701.5100 | 123456 | 1 | 123456 | 1 | CELLALL | 0 | 23.0800 | 123456 | 1 | FITREG | 534.4900 | 3519.0900 | 123456 | 1 | 401K | 502.7400 | null | 123456 | 1 | 401kER | 83.7900 | 0.0000 |
| 950 | 100 | 654321 | 543 | 12 | 123456 | 543 | 2490.9000 | 4189.4800 | 997.0700 | 609.0200 | 701.5100 | 123456 | 2 | 123456 | 2 | SAL | 80 | 4166.4000 | 123456 | 2 | FMEDEE | 58.3100 | 4021.8300 | 123456 | 2 | Dental | 12.6200 | null | 123456 | 2 | AD&D | 0.7500 | 0.0000 |
| 950 | 100 | 654321 | 543 | 12 | 123456 | 543 | 2490.9000 | 4189.4800 | 997.0700 | 609.0200 | 701.5100 | 123456 | 3 | null | null | null | null | null | 123456 | 3 | FSOCEE | 249.3500 | 4021.8300 | 123456 | 3 | FlexMed | 60.0000 | null | 123456 | 3 | FMEDER | 58.3200 | 4021.8300 |
| 950 | 100 | 654321 | 543 | 12 | 123456 | 543 | 2490.9000 | 4189.4800 | 997.0700 | 609.0200 | 701.5100 | 123456 | 4 | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | 123456 | 4 | IdentShd | 3.4600 | null | 123456 | 4 | FSOCER | 249.3500 | 4021.8300 |
| 950 | 100 | 654321 | 543 | 12 | 123456 | 543 | 2490.9000 | 4189.4800 | 997.0700 | 609.0200 | 701.5100 | 123456 | 5 | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | 123456 | 5 | Medical | 84.4100 | null | 123456 | 5 | Life | 1.7500 | 0.0000 |
| 950 | 100 | 654321 | 543 | 12 | 123456 | 543 | 2490.9000 | 4189.4800 | 997.0700 | 609.0200 | 701.5100 | 123456 | 6 | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | 123456 | 6 | Vision | 2.3400 | null | 123456 | 6 | LTD | 8.4100 | 0.0000 |
| 950 | 100 | 654321 | 543 | 12 | 123456 | 543 | 2490.9000 | 4189.4800 | 997.0700 | 609.0200 | 701.5100 | 123456 | 7 | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | 123456 | 7 | VolCan | 8.2800 | null | 123456 | 7 | MedicaER | 206.6600 | 0.0000 |
| 950 | 100 | 654321 | 543 | 12 | 123456 | 543 | 2490.9000 | 4189.4800 | 997.0700 | 609.0200 | 701.5100 | 123456 | 8 | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | 123456 | 8 | VolLifCh | 0.6600 | null | null | null | null | null | null |
| 950 | 100 | 654321 | 543 | 12 | 123456 | 543 | 2490.9000 | 4189.4800 | 997.0700 | 609.0200 | 701.5100 | 123456 | 9 | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | 123456 | 9 | VolLifEE | 27.0000 | null | null | null | null | null | null |
| 950 | 100 | 654321 | 321 | 98 | 987654 | 321 | 2490.9000 | 4189.4800 | 997.0700 | 609.0200 | 701.5100 | 987654 | 1 | 987654 | 1 | CELLALL | 0 | 23.0800 | 987654 | 1 | FITREG | 534.4900 | 3519.0900 | 987654 | 1 | 401K | 502.7400 | null | 987654 | 1 | 401kER | 83.7900 | 0.0000 |
| 950 | 100 | 654321 | 321 | 98 | 987654 | 321 | 2490.9000 | 4189.4800 | 997.0700 | 609.0200 | 701.5100 | 987654 | 2 | 987654 | 2 | PTO | 48 | 2499.8400 | 987654 | 2 | FMEDEE | 58.3100 | 4021.8300 | 987654 | 2 | Dental | 12.6200 | null | 987654 | 2 | AD&D | 0.7500 | 0.0000 |
| 950 | 100 | 654321 | 321 | 98 | 987654 | 321 | 2490.9000 | 4189.4800 | 997.0700 | 609.0200 | 701.5100 | 987654 | 3 | 987654 | 3 | SAL | 32 | 1666.5600 | 987654 | 3 | FSOCEE | 249.3500 | 4021.8300 | 987654 | 3 | FlexMed | 60.0000 | null | 987654 | 3 | FMEDER | 58.3200 | 4021.8300 |
| 950 | 100 | 654321 | 321 | 98 | 987654 | 321 | 2490.9000 | 4189.4800 | 997.0700 | 609.0200 | 701.5100 | 987654 | 4 | null | null | null | null | null | 987654 | 4 | LAITREG | 154.9200 | 3519.0900 | 987654 | 4 | IdentShd | 3.4600 | null | 987654 | 4 | FSOCER | 249.3500 | 4021.8300 |
| 950 | 100 | 654321 | 321 | 98 | 987654 | 321 | 2490.9000 | 4189.4800 | 997.0700 | 609.0200 | 701.5100 | 987654 | 5 | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | 987654 | 5 | Medical | 84.4100 | null | 987654 | 5 | Life | 1.7500 | 0.0000 |
| 950 | 100 | 654321 | 321 | 98 | 987654 | 321 | 2490.9000 | 4189.4800 | 997.0700 | 609.0200 | 701.5100 | 987654 | 6 | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | 987654 | 6 | Vision | 2.3400 | null | 987654 | 6 | LTD | 8.4100 | 0.0000 |
| 950 | 100 | 654321 | 321 | 98 | 987654 | 321 | 2490.9000 | 4189.4800 | 997.0700 | 609.0200 | 701.5100 | 987654 | 7 | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | 987654 | 7 | VolCan | 8.2800 | null | 987654 | 7 | MedicaER | 206.6600 | 0.0000 |
| 950 | 100 | 654321 | 321 | 98 | 987654 | 321 | 2490.9000 | 4189.4800 | 997.0700 | 609.0200 | 701.5100 | 987654 | 8 | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | 987654 | 8 | VolLifCh | 0.6600 | null | null | null | null | null | null |
| 950 | 100 | 654321 | 321 | 98 | 987654 | 321 | 2490.9000 | 4189.4800 | 997.0700 | 609.0200 | 701.5100 | 987654 | 9 | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | 987654 | 9 | VolLifEE | 27.0000 | null | null | null | null | null | null |

(Trimming unwanted columns and assigning distinct column names in the final result is left as an exercise.)

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/E8pX6GB8) for a working example based on the originally posted data.

Comment: Full-join instead of left-join would avoid the need for `CTE_RowNumbers`

Comment: @Charlieface - Yes it could. It would require a progression of coalesce functions for RowNum, ending with `FULL OUTER JOIN CTE_Deductions3 d3 ON d3.CheckID = c.CheckID AND d3.RowNum = COALESCE(p.RowNum, d2.RowNum, d2.RowNum)`. Potentially more efficient, but the statement has less symmetry.

Comment: ... Or do what you did and combine three of the subselects to eliminate the 4-way full outer join. Nice.

Comment: I actually think my way of combining them is neater but less efficient, requires a sort on the row-number for every set.

Comment: You could drop the WHEREs from the inner select, GROUP BY / PARTITION BY CheckID, and then change the CROSS APPLY to a (LEFT?) JOIN on CheckID. See [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/JHhnTxxg). Not sure about performance one way or the other. Once the data is located and retrieved, the differences in in-memory manipulation may be negligible.

Comment: Same thing pretty much, I'd guess: SQL Server is very good at transforming between applys and joins.

Comment: This worked for me, my actual script is pretty long with 7 CTEs including the Row Count one. But I was able to get this working and it produces the results that I was looking for. Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 2):

You can use row-numbering over each set, then combine them using `FULL JOIN`. If you do this all within an `APPLY` then you can do it only once per `Check` row.

You can also combine the last three queries into one, and pivot the results by row-number

```sql
SELECT
  e.Company,
  e.ProcessLevel,
  e.Department,
  e.EmployeeID,
  c.Gross,
  c.Tax,
  c.CompanyDed,
  c.Other,
  c.Net,
  dp.*
FROM Employee e
JOIN [Check] c ON c.EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID
CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT
    p.PSGCheckDescription,
    p.Hours,
    p.WageAmt,
    d.*
  FROM (
    SELECT
      p.PSGCheckDescription,
      SUM(p.Hours) AS Hours,
      SUM(p.WageAmt) AS WageAmt,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS rn
    FROM PSG p
    WHERE c.CheckID = p.CheckID
    GROUP BY
      p.PSGCheckDescription
  ) p
  FULL JOIN (
    SELECT
      d.rn,
      MIN(CASE WHEN d.DedCode = 1 THEN d.DedDescription END) AS DedDescription,
      MIN(CASE WHEN d.DedCode = 1 THEN d.DedAmt         END) AS TaxDed,
      MIN(CASE WHEN d.DedCode = 1 THEN d.TaxWage        END) AS TaxWage,
      MIN(CASE WHEN d.DedCode = 2 THEN d.DedDescription END) AS DedDescription2,
      MIN(CASE WHEN d.DedCode = 2 THEN d.DedAmt         END) AS TaxDed2,
      MIN(CASE WHEN d.DedCode = 2 THEN d.TaxWage        END) AS TaxWage2,
      MIN(CASE WHEN d.DedCode = 3 THEN d.DedDescription END) AS DedDescription3,
      MIN(CASE WHEN d.DedCode = 3 THEN d.DedAmt         END) AS TaxDed3,
      MIN(CASE WHEN d.DedCode = 3 THEN d.TaxWage        END) AS TaxWage3
    FROM (
        SELECT *,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY d.DedCode ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS rn
        FROM Deductions d
        WHERE c.CheckID = d.CheckID
    ) d
    GROUP BY
      d.rn
  ) d ON d.rn = p.rn
) dp;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/hQ_C7zrp)

What this does is as follows:

- Take `Employee` and `Check` rows and join them.
- Within an `APPLY` do the following:
- Take all `PSG` rows for that `Check` row, group them up and row-number the results.
- Take all `Deductions` rows, number them *first*, group up the results by row-number, and take the pivoted results (conditional aggregation using `MIN`).
- Full-join these two sets by row-number. This means we get results for both sides, even when there is no match.